# How to replace slash into underscore in a file name?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, upload, filenames

I want to save a file with mail_number name. I am using

> `$file_name =  $request['mail_number'] . '.' . $extension;`

And it is works. But the problem is, when my mail_number name is include slash('/') character, it won't saved. Do you know how to replace slash('/') with underscore('_') when the file is saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
$file_name =  str_replace('/','_',$request['mail_number']) . '.' . $extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.replace()
Use regex to match all occurrences of `/`

```
$file_name = actual_file_name.replace(/\//g, '_')
```